# Existence and uniquiness or just existence?

Tags: category-theory

Sometimes I am asked to find a morphism which satisfies a property. I am usually reasoning this way: if a morphism $\alpha$ satisfying the property exists, then $\alpha$ is unique with the form $\alpha=x$. My question is: that implication is proving what? That if $\alpha$ exists, then it is unique? That $\alpha$ exists? That $\alpha$ exists unique?

**Example** I want to prove that in any category every split epimorphism is a regular epimorphism. So let $f\colon A\to B$ be a split epimorphism, split by a morphism $g\colon B\to A$. This means that $fg=1_B$. Of course, $fgf=f1_A$. So pick a morphism $q\colon A\to Q$ such that $qgf=q1_A$. I want to show that $q$ factors uniquely over $f$, as $q=\alpha f$, for a unique $\alpha\colon B\to Q$. I say: if such an $\alpha$ exists, then $q=\alpha f$, then $\alpha fg=qg$, then $\alpha=qg$.

My question is: have I already proved that $qg$ is the unique factorization, or should I prove its existence?

Comment: No, you've only proved that *if it exists* it's unique. Also, I'm not sure you wrote what you meant to: "$qfg$" doesn't seem well-defined: since $g:B\rightarrow A$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$, we have $f\circ g: B\rightarrow B$, but $q$ has source $A$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, I've edited. So what I should prove? I guess the existence of $qg$. But $qg$ is just a morphism of the category, so I can't picture what is left to prove.

Comment: You need to prove that $qg$ has the desired property. Otherwise, it's just something that exists *that we don't care about*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all you've proved is that *if it exists* then it is unique. Actually, you've done slightly more: from the hypothesis that $\alpha$ exists you've figured out exactly what it has to be (namely $qg$). However, you haven't shown that this candidate actually has the desired property - namely, that $qgf=q$. You do of course know that $qg$ exists, but you're not being asked to prove $qg$ exists, and what you've shown is just

> If such an $\alpha$ exists, then $\alpha=qg$.

Now **in this case it's actually trivial** that such an $\alpha$ exists - your hypothesis is exactly that $qgf=q1_A$! (Think about what $q1_A$ is.) So really, you've proved the nontrivial part of the theorem, namely that $q$ factors *uniquely* over $f$. So in this particular case, the concern above is pretty vacuous. But there are plenty of examples where it's obvious that the desired object is unique if it exists, but it's far from obvious (or even false!) that it actually exists, so it is very important to separate proofs of existence from proofs of existence-implies-uniqueness.

It might help to first think of a much more concrete situation, like the rational roots theorem: from this, we know that $x^2+x-1=0$ has at most one positive rational solution, namely $x=1$ - but obviously this doesn't tell us that a positive rational solution exists.